# Taking an array and adding <li> for each array place

Tags: jquery, arrays

UPDATE:
Here is the entire function I'm using when a person click to advance a slideshow:

```
$('#navNext').click(function(){
  var current = $('#slider1').find('li.on');

  if(move !==-2695) {
      move = move - amount;
      templateNum = templateNum +1;
      current.removeClass('on');
      current.next().addClass('on');
      var grabAlt = $('.on img').attr('alt').split('|');
      var holdAlt = grabAlt;

   var grabAlt = $('.on img').attr('alt').split('|');
   $('.altDescription').html('<ul><li>' + grabAlt.join('</li><li>') + '</li></ul>');

      letsMove(move);
      $('.templateName').text('Template' + ' '+templateNum);
  }
```

});

NOTE: my 'letsMove(move);' function is declared somewhere else as are other small things. I'm using a fixed-width for images to slide through and currently would have to change the maximum/minimum value..but that's all fine for now. I'm just focusing on the li's now.

I have this:

```
var grabAlt = $('.on img').attr('alt').split('|');
var holdAlt = grabAlt;

$('.altDescription').html('<li>' + holdAlt[0] + '</li>' + '<li>' + holdAlt[1] + '</li>' +     '<li>' + holdAlt[2] + '</li>'+'<li>' + holdAlt[3] + '</li>' +'</ul>');
```

from the code you might see that I'm grabbing the alt text from an image, separating at the piping symbol which throws them into an array, and then make each item a list item. This all works just fine.

What I'm trying to do now is make it more dynamic by saying "for every item in the current array, wrap it in an `<li>,</li>` tag.

I'm playing with `.each()` but I'm getting a little mixed up. I thought it might be something like:

```
$(holdAlt).each(function(){
$('.altDescription').html('<li>' +holdAlt+'</li>');})
```

but I realized I'm not passing a specific item from the array...but the whole array and then...well....fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not the traditional way, this is how I would do it:

```
var grabAlt = $('.on img').attr('alt').split('|');

$('.altDescription').html('<ul><li>' + grabAlt.join('</li><li>') + '</li></ul>');
```

**Note:** This does not take into account the possibility that `grabAlt` might be empty.

Comment: Well, that's cool too but the first item isn't next to a bullet and the the last item is an empty bullet.

Comment: @kelly johnson: What do you mean by that? Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PTWzt/

Comment: well, this is weird. If I add a class to the new ul, I get an issue. no class and just your idea, it works w/no bullets....just a css issue. I will update my post to show the entire function w/your idea.

Comment: @kelly johnson: There's too much stuff going on there. Isolate the parts of the code that are giving you your headache, build a test case on jsFiddle, then post it here so that we might be able to help you...

Comment: Ok, I got this technique to work. Had to alter some actual HTML...go figure..I'm always looking at the javascript/jquery or css...thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this where `this` will point to every item of the array in the loop.

```
$.each(holdAlt, function(){

   $('.altDescription').append('<li>' +this+'</li>');
});
```

Comment: 1) `holdAlt` is an array, and has no `each` method. You might try using `$.each(holdAlt, function() {...})`. 2) You are simply replacing the HTML inside of `.altDescription` on and on...

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the current element within the function you pass to `each()`:

```
$(holdAlt).each(function(){
    $('.altDescription').append('<li>'+this+'</li>');
});
```

Also take a look at the JQuery docs on [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) vs [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: That's nice, but append does just that... it keeps appending. .html() replaces everything in one fell swoop so I'd have to empty the ul then append each time a btn is clicked (unknown by my original post)